# Modal pop up does not hide while using javaScript in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have made modal pop up window, using jQuery. What I want to do is to hide the window if validation was successful. 
Validation has correct values, but still my pop up remains on screen.

Here is my code in js:

```
function validateAndCloseDirectDebitDialog(validationGroup, dialogID) {
         var pageValid = Page_ClientValidate(validationGroup);
         if (pageValid)
            $(dialogID).modal("hide");
         else {
            return false;
         }         
}
```

So when I've did debugging in browser I was able to see that pageValid gets correct value (true - when validation is good) it goes into if loop, but anyhow it does not hide modal.

I've tried doing this as well: `dialogID.modal("hide");`since dialogID is jQuery object, but nothing changed.

I invoke this function from ASP.NET web form button, like this:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpdate" meta:resourcekey="btnUpdate" CausesValidation="False"  OnClientClick = "validateAndCloseDirectDebitDialog('vgDirectDebitApplication' , bankInformation);" />
```

bankInformation is variable defined like this:

```
var bankInformation = $('#<%=bankInfoDialog.ClientID%>');
```

And bankInfoDialog is ID of div that consist out of the controls that are shown on modal:

```
<div id="bankInfoDialog" runat="server" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" style="display: none">×</button>
        <h1 id="bankInformationDialogHeader"><%=GetLocalResourceObject("BankInfoHeader") %></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <ABS:BankInformation runat="server" ID="bankInformation" AllFieldsRequired="True" SetFocusOnError="False" />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpdate" meta:resourcekey="btnUpdate" CausesValidation="False"  OnClientClick = "validateAndCloseDirectDebitDialog('vgDirectDebitApplication' , bankInformation);" />
        <button id="btnCancel" runat="server" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><%=GetLocalResourceObject("Cancel")%></button>
    </div>
</div>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upShortAccountInfo" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="False" EnableViewState="True" >
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpdate" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <ABS:ShortAccountInfo runat="server" ID="shortAccountInfo" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Is there some other way to hide modal in js?

Comment: value of bankInformation variable?

Comment: Are you putting '#' infront of `dialogID`?. Show us some more code.

Comment: @Hemal I will update my question right away with additional code.

Comment: @MuhammadAtif I will add it to my question.

Comment: try using $('[id$=bankInfoDialog]')

Comment: Why are you using server tags for `bankInfoDialog`? You should use direct `#bankInfoDialog`. Server tags `<%%>` are for those controls which are asp.net based.

Comment: @MuhammadAtif I don't think that dialogID aka bankInfoDialog is problem, because it shows validation on the textbox fields... so I guess it gets right modal. But I will try it out for sure... :)

Comment: have tried $(dialogID).modal("hide"); with if else statement for testing?

Comment: @MuhammadAtif I've did not... I will do it right away and let you know what happens...

Comment: @MuhammadAtif With $("#"+dialogID+"").modal("hide"); I get exception: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object HTMLDivElement]

Comment: @Hemal you are right about server tags, my mistake, I will remove them...

Comment: Hmmm, let see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
try sending ID instead of object
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpdate" meta:resourcekey="btnUpdate" CausesValidation="False"  OnClientClick = "validateAndCloseDirectDebitDialog('vgDirectDebitApplication' , 'modalid');" />

And in js

function validateAndCloseDirectDebitDialog(validationGroup, dialogID) {
         var pageValid = Page_ClientValidate(validationGroup);
         if (pageValid)
            $("#"+dialogID+"").modal("hide");
         else {
            return false;
         }         
}
```

Comment: I've try it out like this... Nothing changed... :( @MuhammadAtif

Comment: Nothing helped. It is still visible.@MuhammadAtif